# How do you preserve code that DIDN'T work?

Tags: git, version-control

While developing, I will sometimes try a technique or method that doesn't pan out right away.  Once I decide to move on to another task or try another technique for the same task, I'm never sure what to do with the non-working code.  I want to keep it as a record of what I tried, so I know what didn't work or even as a starting place for trying to make it work again.

Usually I just leave the code in place, commented out and uncommitted to VCS, for some length of time. This becomes a pain however as it clutters code and has to be dodged on VCS commits.  I happen to be using git which has a "stash" function for temporary storage, but I'm not sure if that's an appropriate use.

How do you handle code you want saved for posterity, but don't want as part of your mainstream code base?

Comment: What value does saving broken/dead code provide you, given the overhead to not only store it somewhere, but also to remember that it exists in the first place? Are you going to check this catalogue of horrors before every single checkin? How long will that bad code even stay relevant? I think you're trying to solve a false problem here.

Comment: Shaggy Frog: Even if you didn't manage to reach your goal, you probably managed to solve a number of tangential problems. The need to reuse some of those parts later is not just theoretical; your next attempt is likely to need to solve at least some of those same problems.

Comment: I agree that if done with all non-working code it becomes unmanageable, but if done judiciously it makes sense.  Case in point: trying to use a new feature of a framework but you hit a shipping deadline before you figure it out. You may want to preserve that attempt for later revisiting while you use an older proven method to meet the deadline for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Branches!

1. Use branches liberally ( jQuery_slider_nivo, jQuery_slider_zurb, etc )
2. You're right that stash is not the place to be storing this code for a length of time
3. If you want to check the code simply switch to that branch
4. If you want it back in simply merge the branches

Also you can perform archive operations ( $ = console ):

1. Archive it: $ git checkout -b archive/<branchname> <branchname>
2. Delete it: $ git branch -d <branchname>
3. Restore it: $ git checkout -b <branchname> archive/<branchname>

where <branchname> == TotallyAwesomeBranchName

... or whatever you name your branches =]

Answer (score 5):

Every time you start a "task" create a branch. You can later keep all the things you tried on that branch, and the commit the working code to master.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have created a separate branch for your feature, like `feature/doSomethingCool`. You can now move this (not so cool) branch out of your way like

```
git branch -m feature/doSomethingCool archive/doSomethingCool-try1
```

and create a new branch `feature/doSomethingCool` from `develop`. With the `archive/doSomethingCool-try1`-branch, you can do what you want, even ignoring, or deleting.

- [manpag `git-branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-branch)
- [`git-branch` on the cool new git-scm.com homepage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Comment: (for other readers) the `-m` option is the branch rename option, so with this, after a while you'll have `-try1`, `-try2`, etc. If such explorations are common, start with the `-try1`, etc. until it's the way you want, and simply rename that one.

Comment: In fact (and because this way it's easier to remember) it means "move", but the effect remains the same, right. I'll link to the man-page soon. The suffix `-try1` was symbolic here. I would recommend something more speakable like `myFeature-eventDispatcherApproach`

Comment: +1 for "move". I often think of it as "modify" - any way of remembering is a good way ;-). Naming the approach is good as well, though I'm sure many end up with -luke1, -luke2, (there is no try), - luke3 ...